# why is my JS jQuery not working?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

Trying to setup jQuery and jQuery UI in my rails 3.1.1 app

In my view I have

```
<a href="#" id="test_link1">Test</a>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display:none;">
<p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "#test_link1" ).click(function() {
     ('#dialog-modal').dialog();
  });
```

It's not working. When I inspect I get

```
storages:105TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '('#dialog-modal').show()')
        });
```

In application.js. Files are loaded

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui.min
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `('#dialog-modal').dialog();` to

`$("#dialog-modal").dialog();`

You are forgetting the jQuery($), so there is no jQuery object to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a dollar sign:

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog();
```

Comment: should be a different error, but you could try wrapping it in the doc ready function `$(function(){   //  put code here  });`

Comment: I'd empty the cache and try again. Other than that, be sure that the js files are getting loaded.

Comment: This valid Fiddle jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/QLKxX returns the same error

Comment: It's working for me in chrome, ie, and ff. what browser do you get the error?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in ready handler:

```
$(function(){
  $( "#test_link1" ).click(function() {
     $('#dialog-modal').dialog();
  });
});
```

Comment: Still forgetting the $ on the `("#dialog-modal").dialog();`

Comment: @SamStriano: Updated before seeing your comment :)

Comment: Thanks but error still present `<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $( "#test_link1" ).click(function() {
     $('#dialog-modal').dialog();
  });
});
</script>` gives `storages:106TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#dialog-modal').dialog()')`

Comment: @Gaelle: MAke sure all script are loaded correctly in your page .

Comment: This valid Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/QLKxX/ is not working either so the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @Gaelle: That jsfiddle is working for me, dialog open fine (albeit css isn't applied) , clear the cache and then see please.